# Profiling a COM application?

Tags: vb6, profiling, profiler

I have a big application written in [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) 6 and I need to profile it.
Is there something like [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm) but for [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use [VBWatch](http://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html). I had a good experience with it and it helped me nail down and resolve some pesky performance problems

Comment: I used VBWatch and found problem in 15mins, really great advice thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome, I was quite pleased by it, and I am so glad I don't have to use it anymore;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [VTune from Intel](http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/250099.htm) it has native profiling as well.
If you're having problems using VTune try [AQTime profiler from AutomatedQA](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/)  instead.

Answer (score 1):

[GlowCode](http://www.glowcode.com/) is another good tool.  I've used it successfully with VB6.  The nice part is that you don't need to instrument or recompile your code.  All you need is the symbols (.pdb file) that VB6 can already create for you.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never? VB6 has a "pause" button, right? Not only is it free, and requires no installation, but in my opinion it is [by far the best tool for locating performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Answer (score 0):

[AutomatedQA](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/supported_dev_tools.asp)

That's your best bet.